# Is it possible to use RestAngular.setBaseUrl for two api access points?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

Is it possible to work with Restangular with 2 different APIs?
I would like to have **setBaseUrl()** for both.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

just create two or more Restangular service and config them as you want and inject your module which one you want to use...

**UPDATE**

this code from restangular github page

```
// Global configuration
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://www.global.com');
   RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
});

//First Restangular Service
app.factory('FirstRestangular', function(Restangular) {
   return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
      RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://www.first.com');
   });
});

//Second Restangular Service
app.factory('SecondRestangular', function(Restangular) {
   return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
      RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://www.second.com');
   });
});
```

instead of global config (although you can still set global config for shared properties) create Restangular factories like these and inject them your controller...

```
// Let's use them from a controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(Restangular, FirstRestangular, SecondRestangular) {

  // GET to http://www.google.com/users.json
  // Uses global configuration
  Restangular.all('users').getList()

  // GET to http://www.first.com/users.json
  // Uses First configuration which is based on Global one, therefore .json is added.
  FirstRestangular.all('users').getList()

  // GET to http://www.second.com/users.json
  // Uses Second configuration which is based on Global one, therefore .json is added.
  SecondRestangular.all('users').getList()
});
```

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Comment: @STEVER did you check my update? is it clear for you?

Comment: no, I missed it. 
it is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

@wickY26 has the right answer, but I wanted to add something important.

If you are going to minify your code, you need to use inline annotation like so:

```
app.factory('FirstRestangular', [ 'Restangular', function(Restangular) {
   return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
      RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://www.first.com');
   });
}]);
```

Note the square brackets.