# How to add multiple Auth Interceptor in Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework, restangular

App developed in : ionic + Restangular

I am having one global configuration in Restangular for BaseUrl and Auth Interceptor.[Like for http://app.**.com]

Now, my requirement is to have different set of these.[Like for http://yammer.com]

How do I set different Auth Interceptor and BaseURL for these ?

Aim : Application will have 2 BaseURL and AuthInterceptor.
If I call Yammer,application will communicate only with URL's specefied for Yammer and the if I call any other API's it will communicate with global configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274975/is-it-possible-to-use-restangular-setbaseurl-for-two-api-access-points/22276211#22276211

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz Thanks for the info... what about AuthInterceptor ? How can I send Header for different scenarios ?

Comment: you can check baseurl with a if condition and take different action for different urls...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz problem is with AuthInterceptor header .. Since my application points to 2 different URL  my requirement is to send two different header attributes ... This can be done using true/false logic but is there any standard way to do .. ? As we can create 2 different baseurl similarly can we create 2 different authinterceptor ?

Comment: You can add any number interceptor. So if you want you could split them...

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz It would be better if you post an example .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add as many interceptor as you want by using **addRequestInterceptor** and put your logic to each interceptor.

In your case you can have one or two interceptor which can check baseurl and change header...

```
  RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
    if (url.startsWith('your.base.url2')) {
      // change headers or do whatever you want
    }
    return {
      element: element,
      params: params,
      headers: headers,
      httpConfig: httpConfig
    };
  });

  RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
    if (url.startsWith('your.base.url')) {
      // change headers or do whatever you want
    }
    return {
      element: element,
      params: params,
      headers: headers,
      httpConfig: httpConfig
    };
  });
```

**NOTE:** This interceptor will be triggered at any request and their order will be same with script order at your index.html and second one will get edited request after first one, so you should be carefull when you are using multiple interceptor...